# How to create a static About us page in opencart

Tags: opencart

I am a beginner in using opencart.I need to create an About us page from admin and have to link it to  my main menu navigation.How to get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1** : Goto information link in catalog tab

[image: go to information link in catalog tab]

**Step 2** : click to insert a page or information page like about us

[image: click to insert a page or information like about us]

**Step 3** : if you have enabled seo then you can write keyword for you aboutus page or information page then your url will be easy to use e.g below if seo is disbaled then your url will be little boring e.g(`index.php?route=information/information&information_id=4`)or simpler to it which will not be good to share or use

[image: if you have seo enable then your about us will be aboutus or aboutus.html]

NOTE: for seo you should use `.htaccess` file

Answer (score 0):

It very simple   go to admin panel

catalog -> Information

here you can see all the static pages such as About us,Delivery Information etc
edit them and changes will appear on front page .

to insert new page 
catalog -> Information -> Insert

Comment: I am using pavo themes template hence i cant find any changes in my front end

Comment: http://www.pavothemes.com/demo/?theme=pav_cosmetics I cant find any Information links in my template @ ZIP

Comment: did  you follow the documentation ? http://www.pavothemes.com/guides/framework2/controlpanel/#!/documenter_cover 
check may be your about us page link in footer rather then main menu

Comment: Yes There is no procedure to add static page and link it to menu in this documentation

Comment: most probably you are missing some thing in documentation  , contact with the support of theme provider. or  follow this tutorial and add menu yourself http://www.templatemonster.com/help/opencart-how-to-add-a-new-content-page-and-link-it-to-a-new-menu-tab.html

Answer (score 0):

most complex opencart themes have a module like menu that you almost always can edit in the backend, if you wish to you can add it manually, to do so locate header.tpl in catalog->view->theme->common and see if menu is called directly there probably in a section  or in an external file, probably located in the same folder, if you wish to you can send me a message with further info and i would be glad to further assist you, its really simple, if you find your way around.