# Change URL in OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart

[image]

As shown in the picture, the url is `www.website.com/brand`.

I want to rename the URL directory from `brand` to `Mystuff`, so that it will be `www.website.com/Mystuff`.

What should I do?

Comment: Go to CMS menu in backend and find the url key as brand and change it to mystuff. Ref: https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_home_design.htm

Comment: Sorry its in OpenCart..!!
so wat should i Do??

Comment: You should edit your question and correct it to state *OpenCart* (title and tag).

Comment: ok in backend, try go to catalog menu and find brand page and click edit and in data tab, change seo keyword

Comment: there is'nt any Catalogue menu..??
Can you Instruct me the step clearly??

Comment: In seo keyword you change the page name . see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552992/how-to-create-a-static-about-us-page-in-opencart

Comment: are you using any SEO module?

Comment: I had changed it but the URL has not been changed..!!!

Comment: No I m not using any SEO module

Comment: If you DB access, Please go to phpmyadmin, search where "keyword=brand" from the table 'url_alias', change there it should be worked

Comment: @Samir thnx it worked....!!!

Comment: @Samir Sorry I dont know how to accept the answer?
I thought that i have to write to answer that's why I copied your answer...!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using any third party SEO module and you have DB access, Please go to phpmyadmin, search where "keyword=brand" from the table 'url_alias', change there it should be worked

Answer (score 1):

In order to enable the search engine bots to rank you better, your site must have an identifiable URL that is easy and friendly. However, default URL can sabotage all your efforts to rank better in the search engine’s eye. Here is what you need to do, to ensure a shorter, friendlier and meaningful URL:
Go to the ‘System’ option from the OpenCart dashboard. Click on the ‘Setting’ to avail the ‘Edit’ option. After that, go to the ‘Server’ tab and click ‘YES’ on your website’s ‘SEO URL’. Save the changes.
Rename your site’s file name from the control panel. Change the name from ‘.htaccess.txt’ and rename it to ‘.htaccess’.
Enter the relevant SEO keywords in pages like ‘Information’, ‘Categories’, ‘Products’ and other areas where you want to rewrite the URL.
There are some good plug-ins that you can install to look for better SEO keywords. One such plug-in name is OpenCart SEO Pack.

[Gayas sir](http://www.techfly.in)